# I can't play the song from another device with Spotify API. What could be the problem?

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, spotify

When I start this code on another device with connected Spotify, it plays a totally different song. Please tell me how to fix it.

```
        mSpotifyAppRemote.getPlayerApi()
                .subscribeToPlayerState()
                .setEventCallback(playerState -> {
                    final Track track = playerState.track;
                    
                        mSpotifyAppRemote.getConnectApi().connectSwitchToLocalDevice();
                        mSpotifyAppRemote.getPlayerApi().play(track.uri);
                        
                });
```

Comment: If it's playing but a different song than you intend, are you sure you're passing the correct track uri? Have you debugged your program to ensure?

Comment: Every time I get a different URI. Theoretically, it should be the URI of the song from another device with my Spotify account.